# Google Drive authentication in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement this example,

https://google-developers.appspot.com/drive/auth/web-server

however the following classes are not found! `Oauth2`, `Userinfo`

```
  static User getUserInfo(Credential credentials)
      throws NoUserIdException {
    Oauth2 userInfoService =
        new Oauth2.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credentials).build();
    Userinfo userInfo = null;
    try {
      userInfo = userInfoService.userinfo().get().execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    }
    if (userInfo != null && userInfo.getId() != null) {
      return userInfo;
    } else {
      throw new NoUserIdException();
    }
  }
```

All other classes were found. I have the latest Drive libraries in my build path (Eclipse).

This example is all kinds of messed up. I've implemented OAuth before and this is just way too verbose and over-complicated. It's not even obvious where the user is sent to Google to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

Had to add

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/oauth2/v2

Drive SDK has `com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2`, but not `com.google.api.services.oauth2`! Go figure!

And it STILL doesn't work.

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Userinfo to User

So I had to change the return type to Userinfo.